# Delphi - Saving Records to File using Streams

Tags: delphi, stream

Delphi Tokyo - I have a parameter file that I am needing to save (and later load) from disk.  The parameters are a series of record objects.  There is one HEADER record and then multiple COMMAND records.  These are true records (i.e type = records).  The HEADER record has String, Boolean, Integer, and TStringList types within it.  I save, which appears to work fine, but when I load, whatever is AFTER a TStringList causes a Stream read error.  For example...

```
type tEDP_PROJ = record
   Version : Integer;
   Name: String;
    ...
   ColList1: TStringList;
   ColList2: TStringList;
   ReadyToRun : Boolean;
   ...
 end;
```

When I read ReadyToRun I get a Stream read error.  If I move it BEFORE TStringList (on both SAVE and LOAD routines) then ReadyToRun will load properly, but whatever is after the TStringList will cause an error. It is interesting to note that ColList2 loads fine (even though it is NOT the first TStringList).

I am specifying the Encoding method when I save the TStringList.

```
...
ColList1.SaveToStream(SavingStream, TEncoding.Unicode);
ColList2.SaveToStream(SavingStream, TEncoding.Unicode);
```

I am using the same encoding when I load from the (file) Stream.

```
...
   ColList1.LoadFromStream(SavingStream, TEncoding.Unicode);
   ColList2.LoadFromStream(SavingStream, TEncoding.Unicode);
```

Note that when I create the StringList, I am just doing the standard create...

```
ColList1 := TStringList.Create;
```

When I save and load, I am following the examples Remy gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424546/delphi-write-read-variables-and-records-to-from-file)...

The TStringList appears to be changing the way that the stream reads non-TStringList types...  What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Show [mcve] please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using `TEncoding.Unicode`?  `TEncoding.UTF8` would have made more sense.

In any case, this is not an encoding issue.  What you are attempting to do will simply not work the way you are trying to do it, because `TStrings` data is variable-length and needs to be handled accordingly.  However, `TStrings` does not save any kind of terminating delimiter or size information to an output stream.  When loading in a stream, `TStrings.LoadFromStream()` simply reads the ENTIRE stream (well, everything between the current `Position` and the End-Of-Stream, anyway).  That is why you are getting streaming errors when trying to read/write any non-`TStrings` data after any `TStrings` data.

Just like [the earlier code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424546/delphi-write-read-variables-and-records-to-from-file) needed to serialize `String` data and other variable-length data into a flat format to know where one field ends and the next begins, you need to serialize `TStrings` data as well.

One option is to save a `TStrings` object to an intermediate `TMemoryStream` first, then write that stream's `Size` to your output stream followed by the `TMemoryStream`'s data.  When loading back later, first read the `Size`, then read the specified number of bytes into an intermediate `TMemoryStream`, and then load that stream into your receiving `TStrings` object:

```
procedure WriteInt64ToStream(Stream: TStream; Value: Int64);
begin
  Stream.WriteBuffer(Value, Sizeof(Value));
end;

function ReadInt64FromStream(Stream: TStream): Int64;
begin
  Stream.ReadBuffer(Result, Sizeof(Result));
end;

procedure WriteStringsToStream(Stream: TStream; Values: TStrings);
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  Size: Int64;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Values.SaveToStream(MS, TEncoding.UTF8);
    Size := MS.Size;
    WriteInt64ToStream(Stream, Size);
    if Size > 0 then
    begin
      MS.Position := 0;
      Stream.CopyFrom(MS, Size);
    end;
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure ReadStringsFromStream(Stream: TStream; Values: TStrings);
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  Size: Int64;
begin
  Size := ReadInt64FromStream(Stream);
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    if Size > 0 then
    begin
      MS.CopyFrom(Stream, Size);
      MS.Position := 0;
    end;
    Values.LoadFromStream(MS, TEncoding.UTF8);
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Another option is to write the number of string elements in the `TStrings` object to your output stream, and then write the individual strings:

```
procedure WriteStringsToStream(Stream: TStream; Values: TStrings);
var
  Count, I: Integer;
begin
  Count := Values.Count;
  WriteIntegerToStream(Stream, Count);
  for I := 0 to Count-1 do
    WriteStringToStream(Stream, Values[I]);
end;

procedure ReadStringsFromStream(Stream: TStream; Values: TStrings);
var
  Count, I: Integer;
begin
  Count := ReadIntegerFromStream(Stream);
  if Count > 0 then
  begin
    Values.BeginUpdate;
    try
      for I := 0 to Count-1 do
        Values.Add(ReadStringFromStream(Stream));
    finally
      Values.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Either way, you can then do this when streaming your individual records:

```
WriteIntegerToStream(SavingStream, Version);
WriteStringToStream(SavingStream, Name);
...
WriteStringsToStream(SavingStream, ColList1);
WriteStringsToStream(SavingStream, ColList2);
WriteBooleanToStream(SavingStream, ReadyToRun);
```

```
Version := ReadIntegerFromStream(SavingStream);
Name := ReadStringFromStream(SavingStream);
...
ReadStringsFromStream(SavingStream, ColList1);
ReadStringsFromStream(SavingStream, ColList2);
ReadyToRun := ReadBooleanFromStream(SavingStream);
```

Comment: @@Remy - I assumed that TStringList.LoadFromStream would only load itself from a stream and then stop, not expect to 'own' the rest of the stream.  Regardless, I used your  MemoryStream approach and it worked beautifully.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @user1009073 `SaveToFile()` calls `SaveToStream()`, and the resulting file can be opened in a text editor. So `SaveToStream()` saves in a very simple format that does not allow `LoadFrom(Stream/File)()` to know how many strings belong to it, so it has no choice but to load the rest of the stream.